# Convert a column into a list

Tags: python-2.7

I need to apply a for loop on a file containing records of a command, to convert one of the column into a list. Please advise, Thanks in advance .

Data is as below :

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             
asset           8          100             1009663         1             
asset           7          200             523533          1               
asset           9          319710          319710          0              
asset           5          870935          870935          0
```

This is my code :

```
lag_list = []
with open(fname) as f:
    f.readline()
    lines = f.readlines()[1: ]
    length = len(lines)
    print(length)
    for line in lines:
        print "Hello"
        print line
        print "hello 2"
        data=line.split(' ')
        lag_list.append(data[4])
        data=line.split("\t")
        lag_list.append(data[4])
    print lag_list
return
```

But returning this error:

```
lag_list.append(data[4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Apparently not all of your lines contain five space-separated items. Have you done any debugging to find out what the line *does* contain?

Answer (score 0):

Your data has 
- not 4 tabs in a line 
- or not 4 spaces in a line 
- or you have a `\n` after the last line of your source data

When reading those lines and splitting them, you do not have 5 elements in the resulting list - hence index error when accessing `data[4]`.

Splitting the same list by spaces and by tabs does not make much sense for me - I hope it does for your data and application.

Check your splitted list before indexing into it:

```
lag_list = []

with open(fname) as f:
    f.readline()
    lines = f.readlines()[1: ]
    length = len(lines)
    print(length)
    for line in lines:
        print "Hello"
        print line
        print "hello 2"
        data = line.split(' ') 
        if len(data) >= 5:                 # check if safe to index into
            lag_list.append(data[4]     
        else:
            print("Not enough elements - need 5 at least:", data)
        data = line.split("\t")
        if len(data) >= 5:                 # check if safe to index into
            lag_list.append(data[4])
        else:
            print("Not enough elements - need 5 at least:", data)
    print lag_list
return
```